# Hide div when using qtip

Tags: jquery, html, qtip, qtip2

Maybe this is a dummy question, but... what's the way to hide a div when the html loads and then show it via qTip?
I tried to hide it with `$(div).hide` and `<div style="display: none;">`, but the qtip doesn't work.

**UPDATE**

Code in the .js

```
$('#usuario').qtip({
    content: $(this).next(),
    show: 'click',
    hide: 'unfocus'
});
```

Code in the html

```
<span id='usuario_menu'>
            <a id="usuario" ><?php echo $_SESSION['correo']; ?></a>
            <div class="hidden">
                <a href="php/login_out.php">Cerrar sesión</a><br/>
                <a href="">Otra cosa</a>
            </div>
            <img src='' alt="Tareas pendientes">
        </span>
```

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to apply qTip in div content?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975160/how-to-apply-qtip-in-div-content)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**
The answer is among the comments on this:
[jQuery qTip: How to attach a single tooltip div to multiple target divs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996870/jquery-qtip-how-to-attach-a-single-tooltip-div-to-multiple-target-divs)

However, if there anothers answers, they are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

As I stumbled over this question when I did not get the hidden element method for qtip working and did not get an answer for me here, I will post some working code, after I have solved the problem. Just for others to look up.

Your problem was `$(this)` in your js code. You can exchange it with `$("#usuario")`. If you use a class "hidden" in your div, you should hide it by applying a css rule to this class: `.hidden{ display:none; }`. The rest of your code was ok, I just changed your php code to "test", because I do not use your server :-).

And here is the code:

```
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.qtip.css" />
</head>
<body>
<span id='usuario_menu'>
            <a id="usuario" >test</a>
            <div class="hidden">
                <a href="php/login_out.php">Cerrar sesión</a><br/>
                <a href="">Otra cosa</a>
            </div>
            <img src='' alt="Tareas pendientes">
        </span>
</body>

<style>
.hidden{ display:none; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.qtip.js"></script>
<script>
$('#usuario').qtip({
content: $("#usuario").next(),
show:'click',
hide:'unfocus'
});
</script>
```

One has to include the files jquery.qtip.css, jquery-3.4.1.js, jquery-3.4.1.js in the same directory as the above html file, than it runs. You can try yourself in the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lf6s9um4/. Just click on the word "test".

Certainly this is not the best solution, if you want to use many hidden many divs and use them to show the tooltips. Then you should look in the qtip2 guide http://qtip2.com/guides for "hidden element".